# How to get pdf filename with Python requests?

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests, filenames

I'm using the Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library to get a PDF file from the web. This works fine, but I now also want the original filename. If I go to a PDF file in Firefox and click `download` it already has a filename defined to save the pdf. How do I get this filename?

For example:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.researchgate.net/profile/M_Gotic/publication/260197848_Mater_Sci_Eng_B47_%281997%29_33/links/0c9605301e48beda0f000000.pdf')
print r.headers['content-type']  # prints 'application/pdf'
```

I checked the `r.headers` for anything interesting, but there's no filename in there. I was actually hoping for something like `r.filename`..

Does anybody know how I can get the filename of a downloaded PDF file with the requests library?

Comment: Interesting – I was going to say, "well *obviously* `0c9605301e48beda0f000000.pdf`" (as that is in the request) but fortunately I decided to test it first. And FireFox wants to save it as "Mater Sci Eng B47 (1997) 33.pdf".

Comment: How are you checking the headers? The filename _is_ there, `content-disposition : inline; filename="Mater Sci Eng B47 (1997) 33.pdf"`. FWIW, many PDFs have a [Title](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6367304/4014959) embedded in them, but not all, and it may not be easy to access if the PDF is in binary form.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It is specified in an http header `content-disposition`. So to extract the name you would do:

```
import re
d = r.headers['content-disposition']
fname = re.findall("filename=(.+)", d)[0]
```

Name extracted from the string via regular expression (`re` module).

Comment: This wouldn't work if the file name is encoded as utf8. Any suggestion there?

Comment: findall returns a list of matches. You would need an index like this `fname = re.findall("filename=(.+)", d)[0]`.

Comment: This one is incomplete, a filename can we enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @Michael-O try using `"filename=\"(.+)\""` to remove quotes

Comment: Just a side case that sometimes expected filenames are not provided within headers, especially with social media CDN links. In that case, you can formulate your own base name (maybe parse the url for the root filename that you would like to use), and then ascertain the correct extension to use as a suffix with something like `resp.headers['Content-Type'].split('/')[-1]`.

Comment: In my case, the regex did not work because my `'content-disposition'` also contains `filename=*UTF-8`: 
`'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=NameOfTheFile.zip; filename*=UTF-8''NameOfTheFile.zip"`

Comment: You can use `cgi.parse_header` and `email.header.decode_header` to parse the file name properly

Comment: @vvvvv @tony-abou-assaleh, I use `unquote(header.split("filename*=")[1].replace('UTF-8\'\'',""))` for Unicode

Answer (score 23):

Building on some of the other answers, here's how I do it. If there isn't a `Content-Disposition` header, I parse it from the download URL:

```
import re
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException


url = 'http://www.example.com/downloads/sample.pdf'

try:
    with requests.get(url) as r:

        fname = ''
        if "Content-Disposition" in r.headers.keys():
            fname = re.findall("filename=(.+)", r.headers["Content-Disposition"])[0]
        else:
            fname = url.split("/")[-1]

        print(fname)
except RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```

There are arguably better ways of parsing the URL string, but for simplicity I didn't want to involve any more libraries.

Comment: I suggest calling `urllib.parse.unquote` in the else clause so you don't get `%20`s in the filename.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, for this particular resource it is in:

```
r.headers['content-disposition']
```

Don't know if it is always the case, though.

Comment: Not all responses contain the 'content-disposition' header, but as per one of the comments, it seems they are available in this case.

Answer (score 9):

easy python3 implementation to get filename from Content-Disposition:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(<your-url>)
print(response.headers.get("Content-Disposition").split("filename=")[1])
```

Comment: Be careful in case there is no "Content-Disposition" header!

Comment: could use  something like `response.headers.get("Content-Disposition","filename=output.bin")` to cover the missing header.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `werkzeug` for options headers https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/http/#werkzeug.http.parse_options_header

```
>>> import werkzeug


>>> werkzeug.http.parse_options_header('text/html; charset=utf8')
('text/html', {'charset': 'utf8'})
```

Comment: This is the most robust option as it removes optional quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) instead of `requests` because then you can do `urllib.request.urlopen(`...`).`[`headers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.response.addinfourl.headers)`.`[`get_filename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_filename), which is safer than some of the other answers for the following reason:

> If the [*Content-Disposition*] header does not have a `filename` parameter, this method falls back to looking for the `name` parameter on the *Content-Type* header.

After that, even safer would be to additionally fall back to the filename in the URL, as another answer does.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, neither `Content-Disposition` nor its `filename` attribute is required. Also, I checked dozens links on the internet and haven't found responses with the `Content-Disposition` header. So, in most cases, I wouldn't rely on it much and just retrieve this information from the request URL (note: I'm taking it from `req.url` because there could be redirection and we want to get *real* filename). I used [`werkzeug`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/) because it looks more robust and handles quoted and unquoted filenames. Eventually, I came up with this solution (works since Python 3.8):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
import werkzeug


def get_filename(url: str):
    try:
        with requests.get(url) as req:
            if content_disposition := req.headers.get("Content-Disposition"):
                param, options = werkzeug.http.parse_options_header(content_disposition)
                if param == 'attachment' and (filename := options.get('filename')):
                    return filename

            path = urlparse(req.url).path
            name = path[path.rfind('/') + 1:]
            return name
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise e
```

I wrote some tests using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/) and [`requests_mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import pytest
import requests
import requests_mock

from main import get_filename

TEST_URL = 'https://pwrk.us/report.pdf'


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'headers,expected_filename',
    [
        (
                {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.pdf"'},
                "filename.pdf"
        ),
        (
                # The string following filename should always be put into quotes;
                # but, for compatibility reasons, many browsers try to parse unquoted names that contain spaces.
                # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#directives
                {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=filename with spaces.pdf'},
                "filename with spaces.pdf"
        ),
        (
                {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;'},
                "report.pdf"
        ),
        (
                {'Content-Disposition': 'inline;'},
                "report.pdf"
        ),
        (
                {},
                "report.pdf"
        )
    ]
)
def test_get_filename(headers, expected_filename):
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
        m.get(TEST_URL, text='resp', headers=headers)
        assert get_filename(TEST_URL) == expected_filename


def test_get_filename_exception():
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
        m.get(TEST_URL, exc=requests.exceptions.RequestException)
        with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.RequestException):
            get_filename(TEST_URL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python's standard library:

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg["Content-Disposition"] = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition")
filename = msg.get_filename()
```

Like others said, the file name is in the "Content-Disposition" header.

The `cgi` standard library module used to be the way to parse it, but it's deprecated since `py311`.

The currently recommended way of parsing is using the `email` module, which is also part of the standard library.

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html
- https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_filename

Answer (score 0):

For me (with requests `2.31`) worked with lower caps and with the code bellow:

```
import request

response = requests.get(file_url)
content_disposition = response.headers.get("content-disposition")
file_name = content_disposition.split("=")[1]
```