# How to download a file from an url and keep its name and metadata with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

In the browser if I click on a download button, a file will be downloaded with its original name and metadata.

Currently I can download a file with python requests, but I have to give it a name and none of the metadata is available with the downloaded file.

Files that I want to download have meaningful names, but these names are not part of the url.

What is the best way to do this with python?

Only these headers are in the response:

- Server
- Date
- Content-Type
- Connection
- Vary
- X-Powered-By
- Pragma
- Set-Cookie
- Expires
- Cache-Control
- Link
- Content-Encoding

`Content-Disposition` header is not available in `r.headers` but I can see it if I download the file in the browser.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 53, in <module>
    print r.headers["Content-Disposition"]
  File "/Users/raitis.dembovskis/.virtualenvs/webcrawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'content-disposition'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get pdf filename with Python requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804799/how-to-get-pdf-filename-with-python-requests)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done only if header of that url has the information of file name:

```
result.urllib2.urlopen(url)
result.headers['content-disposition']
or
result.info()
```

Comment: this header is not available

Answer (score 0):

The file name is set by server using Content-Disposition header as follows:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"
```

so, try to read from headers and extract filename given in the header and use it.

Reference:

1. [How to set name of file downloaded from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102226/how-to-set-name-of-file-downloaded-from-browser)

Comment: this header is not available

Comment: capture the request using network sniffing tool (burp suite, Wireshark) or browser  (F12 -> Network tab) and check the headers. Browser uses the header to give a name to the file. so, it should be present.

Comment: this header is present in the browser but if i check 'response.headers' its not there

Comment: is it publicly accessible url (to download)? If yes, share with us, will try. Or share similar URL

Comment: Try with browser User-Agent header such as "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0" instead of default value in request headers.

Comment: So I didn't change anything and now `Content-Disposition` is available. Before I also tried with setting user agent, but this header just wasn't there.

Comment: Haha, yes. I should delete this question.