# Getting the filename and extension form a URL in python

Tags: python, file, download, file-extension

So I am making this downloader app in python **using tkinter and urllib.request** and I want to give the user the option to have the file downloaded with default name and extension. And I know that there are MILLIONS of tutorials out there on how to do this, but my problem is with this specific URL:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR9JHQ-y1AyCjkJt3gl0jTtNtQdhv0lCdDYxqnc2wY9zy_hSOSy
I have tried many codes like **wget and urlparse** but none of them were able to get the extension of this file from its URL. So is there any other way?
The wget command:

```
url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR9JHQ-y1AyCjkJt3gl0jTtNtQdhv0lCdDYxqnc2wY9zy_hSOSy'
test = wget.detect_filename(url)
print(test)
```

The output with the mentioned URL:

```
images
```

The urllib.parse command:

```
url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR9JHQ-y1AyCjkJt3gl0jTtNtQdhv0lCdDYxqnc2wY9zy_hSOSy'
path = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path
ext = os.path.splitext(path)[1]
print(path)
print(ext)
```

The output with the mentioned URL:

```
/images
```

Is there something wrong with the URL?

Comment: what is the expected filename?

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804799/how-to-get-pdf-filename-with-python-requests

Comment: That's because your URL is not sending an image file with a file name and extension. It's just being dynamically rendered in your browser.

Comment: As others have noted, you can't get the extension because the URL has no extension -- if you wanted you could do something sneaky like deducing the mime type from the file header and in turn suggesting an appropriate extension from that, using [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) or the like.  This would require reading the first few bits of the file though...

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get MIME type from the response headers, then use [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/mimetypes.html) to get an extension to suggest

```
import requests, mimetypes

r = requests.get('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR9JHQ-y1AyCjkJt3gl0jTtNtQdhv0lCdDYxqnc2wY9zy_hSOSy')
r.headers
{'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Length': '4517', 'Date': 'Sun, 19 Apr 2020 09:23:26 GMT', 'Expires': 'Mon, 19 Apr 2021 09:23:26 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Fri, 15 Jan 2016 11:47:48 GMT', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Server': 'sffe', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000', 'Age': '840', 'Alt-Svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000'}

r.headers['Content-Type']
'image/jpeg'

mimetypes.guess_all_extensions(r.headers['Content-Type'], strict=False)
['.jpe', '.jpeg', '.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can also change the extension and the name of output file by editing the final_file_name variable. For the answer, I have left it as "image.jpg".

```
import requests

final_url = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR9JHQ-y1AyCjkJt3gl0jTtNtQdhv0lCdDYxqnc2wY9zy_hSOSy"
final_file = requests.get(final_url)
final_file_name = "image.jpg"
open(final_file_name,"wb").write(final_file.content)
```